# How can i get products displayed with predefined quantities in magento?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, product, mage

I have some simple products setup that have various custom options, some of which are set to required. What I would like to do is get the products set up to where the customer can choose from predefined quantities for a certain price.

For example say the product is a widget, i want the customer to be able to choose from say 100 for $20, 200 for $35, 500 for $80 ..... and so on.

Tiered Pricing doesn't work since the prices are increasing.

I tried using a custom options which worked out price-wise BUT it did not update the total weight of the product which I need calculated in order to calculate shipping quotes.

I also tried using group products and setting the products within the group as the specific quantities and setting the calculated weights BUT it doesn't allow me to keep the custom options i have set as required.

So right now I'm just at a lost. Any Ideas how i can get this setup with the predefined quantities that also updates weight for shipping?

I'm using magento 1.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some more searching I found something that works....

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/73036/